# Adjust font in Plotly graph to match Base R Plot

Tags: r, plot, fonts, plotly

I am plotting something using Plotly (3D Surface Plot). Minimal Example:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>% add_surface() %>% layout(title=list(text="<b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b>", font=list(color="black")))
```

[image]
However, most of the plots I additionally have in my presentation are made with the base R plot command. Minimal example:

```
par(font=2)
plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$hp, main="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
```

[image]

Now I would like to have all my plots in a consistent way. I already figured out ways to have the colours, backgrounds and title position similar. However the titles itself look a bit different. Is it possible to use for the plotly title the same font as in the base R plot? Or if this does not work, would the other way around be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `plotly` you can change the font family just inside the title argument or you can change the font of the whole plot

```
# Change font of title
plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>% 
  add_surface() %>% 
  layout(title=list(text="<b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b>", 
                    font=list(color="black", family = "Helvetica")))

# Change font for whole plot
plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>% 
  add_surface() %>% 
  layout(title=list(text="<b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b>", 
                    font=list(color="black")),
         font = list(family = "Helvetica"))
```

[image]